# How can I find which one of 2 HDDs is newer?

Tags: hard-drive

I have 2 hard drives and I really need to find which one was used latest. (they're both broken but I only want to repair newer). Can I somehow figure out which one is newer? labels does not state date of manufacture.

LABELS:
[HDD1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK9t7.jpg)

[HDD2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slmFm.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If they're mechanically broken, but electronics is OK, diagnostic tools may still be used to determine which one is the least used. This has nothing to do with the production date, though.

You can read the production date on the HGST drive: January  2015 (JAN-15).

The Toshiba MK6465GSX was introduced in 2009 (see [here](https://www.toshiba.co.jp/about/press/2009_09/pr0201.htm)) and apparently not produced after Q4 2013 (see [here](https://hdd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/994/TOSHIBA-MK6465GSX))

With regards to the production date, you can reasonably consider the HGST a "newer" model than the Toshiba.